# How to manage next and previous button in custom video player

Tags: swift, avplayer, avkit

I am playing video using avkit. so I have multiple video files and i want to play next and previous song on the button click.
i am doing this to play video -:

```
  func playVideo(){
    let url = URL(string: historyArray[videoUrlIndex].value(forKey:kConstant.keyName.urlString) as! String)
    player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resize
    player.currentItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "duration", options: [.new,.initial], context: nil)
    addTimeObserver()
    videoView.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
    playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    pip = AVPictureInPictureController(playerLayer: playerLayer)
}
```

and in view will appear i am doing this -:

```
 playVideo()
 player.play()
```

This is what i am doing on next and previous button -:

```
 @IBAction func rewindButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if videoUrlIndex > 0 {
       videoUrlIndex = videoUrlIndex - 1
        playVideo()
        player.play()
    }

}

@IBAction func fastforwardButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if videoUrlIndex >= 0 {
       videoUrlIndex = videoUrlIndex + 1
        playVideo()
        player.play()
    }

}
```

But this is not working fine what is wrong with this code

Comment: I think you need to clean the previous video. Try cleaning previous layer before adding a new sublayer using```playerLayer. removeFromSuperlayer()``` &  ```videoView.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()```

Comment: Even now multiple video sound coming when click on the next button @udi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare class variable `var player = AVPlayer?` and in you  `playVideo()` function add `self.player = player`. When you want to replace video try this:

```
    func replaceVideo() {
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "videoURL")!)
    self.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you are not removing the previous video layer before adding the new one. Thats why multiple video sounds come together.

Following example works for me.

```
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
var player: AVPlayer?
    
var urls : [String] = ["http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4","http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"]
```

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    self.view.addSubview(self.nextButton)
        
    self. nextButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    self. nextButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    self. nextButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    self. nextButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

    self.playVideo(index: 1)
    player!.play()

 }
```

```
func playVideo(index : Int){
        
    let videoURL : URL = URL(string: urls[index])!
    player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        
    let newPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    newPlayerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds

    playerLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

    self.view!.layer.addSublayer(newPlayerLayer)
        
    playerLayer = newPlayerLayer

}
```

```
public lazy var nextButton: UIButton = {
        
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    button.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(next(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)        
        
    return button
        
}()
```

```
@objc func next(_ sender: UIButton){
    self.playVideo(index: 0)
    player!.play()

}
```

Comment: This code working fine on the simulator but when I run this code on phone again multiple sounds come